# Given a FOR EACH ROW trigger that runs on INSERT, will multi-value INSERT or COPY be faster in PostgreSQL (with regards to triggers) and why?

Tags: postgresql

Out of curiosity, I tested it myself. It seems like COPY is materially faster than multi-value INSERT when it comes to triggers.

- I inserted 100,000 rows into a simple table in PostgreSQL 14
- The triggers took 45s when triggered by multi-value INSERT
- The triggers took 1.5s when triggered by COPY

(The trigger is a simple record_history trigger, copying a row from the main table to a matching history table)

Is this an expected result?

Here is the trigger for reference

```sql
BEGIN

IF ("public"._pgtrigger_should_ignore(TG_NAME) IS TRUE) THEN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END IF;

if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
insert into history ("id", "uuid") values(new."id", new."uuid"); return new;
elsif (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
insert into history ("id", "uuid") values(new."id", new."uuid"); return new;
elsif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
insert into history ("id", "uuid") values(old."id", old."uuid"); return old;
end if;

END;
```

And the code that registers the trigger.

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS pgtrigger_record_history ON "history";
CREATE TRIGGER pgtrigger_record_history
AFTER DELETE OR UPDATE OR INSERT ON "studies"
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE pgtrigger_record_history();
```

Comment: Are the INSERTs executed in a single transaction?

Comment: Also, it would help, for reproduction purposes anyway, to have the definition of the trigger. You can use a [fiddle](https://db-fiddle.uk) for this.

Comment: @dwhitemv - yes to single transaction, and that is the trigger above

Comment: Can you also provide the CREATE TRIGGER statement for the table you were importing data into? The deferral setting is important.

Comment: Yup, added @dwhitemv